# How to handle serverside dependency available only during runtime with webpack

Tags: javascript, pug, bundle, webpack, require

We have a file requiring a jade template rendered on server side during runtime.

```
define(['underscore', 'html!/templates/myTemplate'], function (_, template){
    ...
})
```

The idea is to bundle the other dependencies (here underscore) on compile but require the template only on runtime.

We tried using externals like this but it didn't change anything.

```
externals: {
    '/templates/myTemplate': '/templates/myTemplate'
}
```

But the same error is displayed when we compile the bundle:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /templates/myTemplate ...
```

Any idea?

Here is our settings file

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    "pageA": "./pageA.js",
    "pageB": "./pageB.js"
  },

  output: {
    "path": __dirname + '/dist',
    "publicPath": './javascripts/dist/',
    "filename": '[name].js'
  },

  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery"
      })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Use `require(['dependency'], callback(dependency){});`

Comment: As shown [here](https://gist.github.com/sokra/8805639#file-webpack-js-L11-L20)

Comment: Same issue, webpack tries to load the template at compile time if I put it in a separate require inside the original define callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using Webpack only: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2326